# Why transmission of chopped data with specific size is more rapid than whole of it at once

Tags: networking, scientific-computing, transmission

Consider you're going to transfer a file with specific size over the network,
Once you try this by transferring whole of the file contentiously , 
And Once by chopping the file into more small piece of data then transferring  it?

Obviously , the second try is supposed to be much more faster than transmission of a massive file is contentiously sending ?

Such this work is used by many applications (for example, download managers) to increment transmission speed, But why ?

What's the concept of behind that ?